# How to fill up empty cells by linear interpolation

Tags: excel, vba

I got three columns of interest: One with a timestamp in milliseconds and two with data. If there is a row containing data 1, then the cell with data 2 is empty and vice versa. Now I want to fill up the empty cells by linear interpolation. The order the data is coming is variable and the difference of the timestamps is also variable.

```
timestamp 1  data 1
timestamp 2  data 1
timestamp 3  data 1
timestamp 4          data 2
timestamp 5  data 1
timestamp 6          data 2
timestamp 7          data 2
timestamp 8  data1
timestamp 9  data1
```

I thought about using the Trend-function somehow, but I don't know how to manage that only the last row bevore and the first after the "whole" is used to interpolate the values according to the timestamps. 
Any ideas on that?

Thanks a lot for suggestions!!
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interpolation for internal values is pretty quickly accomplished by a quick for each loop.

```
Sub interpolate()
For Each cell In Range("B1:B14")
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        y2 = cell.End(xlDown).Value
        x2 = cell.End(xlDown).Offset(0, -1).Value
        y1 = cell.End(xlUp).Value
        x1 = cell.End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1).Value
        x = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        y = (y1) + (x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
        cell.Value = y
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

As you correctly identify, this methodology can't properly address blank spaces at the boundaries though, and will break. If the relationship between the timestamp and the data is reliably linear, you could modify that a bit to extrapolate known data into the boundary positions. For example, by using data2(t=4) and data2(t=6) for y1 and y2 in the interpolation equation. If you made sure to apply this extrapolation first, filling the boundary positions, the previous code should work for the whole range. Alternately, you could do a Trend for the whole dataset maybe. Keep in mind, though, this is a least squares fit to a straight line, and will only work if the data is a linear function of time. If it's not, this will totally lie to you. My solution is below, and should work, but I'm a total hack, so its probably inelegant and messy.

```
Sub trendlinefit()
Dim xData1() As Double
Dim yData1() As Double
Dim newxData1() As Double
Dim xData2() As Double
Dim yData2() As Double
Dim newxData2() As Double
Dim tcell As Range

Set rangeData1 = Range("B1:B14")
Set rangeData2 = Range("C1:C14")
Set tcell = Range("G18")

'loops through data 1 cells and builds arrays for known and needed values'
a = 0
b = 0
For Each cell1 In rangeData1
    If cell1.Value <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve xData1(a)
        ReDim Preserve yData1(a)
        xData1(a) = cell1.Offset(0, -1).Value   'unknown x value for data 1'
        yData1(a) = cell1.Value                 'unknown y value for data 1'
        a = a + 1
    ElseIf cell1.Value = "" Then
        ReDim Preserve newxData1(b)
        newxData1(b) = cell1.Offset(0, -1).Value    'missing x value data 1'
        b = b + 1
    End If
Next

'loops through data 2 cells and builds arrays for known and needed values'
j = 0
k = 0
For Each cell2 In rangeData2
    If cell2.Value <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve xData2(j)
        ReDim Preserve yData2(j)
        xData2(j) = cell2.Offset(0, -2).Value   'unknown x value for data 2'
        yData2(j) = cell2.Value                 'unknown y value for data 2'
        j = j + 1
    ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then
        ReDim Preserve newxData2(k)
        newxData2(k) = cell2.Offset(0, -2).Value    'missing x value data 2'
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next

'curve fitting functions. In this case, Trend.'
result1 = WorksheetFunction.Trend(yData1, xData1, newxData1)
result2 = WorksheetFunction.Trend(yData2, xData2, newxData2)

'populate data1 with result1' 
q = 1
For Each fcell1 In rangeData1
    If fcell1.Value = "" Then
        fcell1.Value = result1(q)
        q = q + 1
    End If
Next

'populate data2 with result2'
r = 1
For Each fcell2 In rangeData2
    If fcell2.Value = "" Then
        fcell2.Value = result2(r)
        r = r + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Most of that code just generates arrays for use by the Trend function (towards the bottom). If the data isn't linear though, you would probably need to scrap the Trend function and generate `result1` and `result2` through some more sophisticated curve-fitting technique, which would give you a better chance of calculating those boundary values. Unfortunately, any approach requires a bit of design input, but hopefully this gets you started.